# Including the Google gdata finance jar in my Android Project

Tags: android, gdata

I have included the Google gdata finance jar in my Android project (included the jar file in the build set). However still when I make any calls to functions in that jar, I still get a NoClassDeffound Exception. I believe this means that during execution the particular class is not being found by the emulator. Any ways I can fix this problem?

And I am including the com.google.gdata.client.finance.* via the import statements.

UPDATE: I solved the problem. It was more gdata specific. The problem was that I was not including the core gdata files: gdata-client, gdata-client-meta, gdata-core, and gdata-media.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that your JAR is not being packaged with your application, for some reason. Make sure the JAR is in the `libs/` directory of the project.

Comment: Yes, the JAR is in the libs directory of my project and I have added the jar to the build set of the project from the libs folder.

Comment: Does unpacking the jar and placing the individual classes in the libs folder help ?

Comment: @Titan: It hurts. Are you sure that the class that is raising the `NoClassDefFound` exception is a `com.google.gdata.client.finance` class?